# Add a new column that equals to another column one index before in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
date <- as.Date(c('2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03'))
value <- c(5,6,7)
df <- data.frame(date, value)
```

I want to create other 2 columns `val_1`,`val_2` that equals to respectively `value` and `val_1` that are one index before:

```
date        value   val_1   val_2
2020-01-01    5      NA      NA
2020-01-01    6      5       NA
2020-01-01    7      6       5
```

how do I do that?

Comment: Use `library(dplyr)`, and you can do `lag(value, 1)` and `lag(value, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sapply` to manipulate the `length`s.

```
df <- setNames(cbind(df, sapply(1:2, function(i) 
  c(rep(NA, i), x[-(length(x):(length(x)-(i-1)))]))),
  c(names(df), paste0("val_", 1:2)))
df
#         date value val_1 val_2
# 1 2020-01-01     5    NA    NA
# 2 2020-01-02     6     5    NA
# 3 2020-01-03     7     6     5
```